# Blazor .NET 6 Component EventHandler Parameter Dont work in parent handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I use .NET 6 and visual Studio 2022
I have a Component with EventHandler Like below

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<DIMCustomer> OnSelectedCustomer { get; set; }
```

and in a method in this component invoke this event like below

```
async Task Select(DIMCustomer customer)
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Detached;
            await OnSelectedCustomer.InvokeAsync(customer);
            await CloseModal();
        }
```

in Parent I Use this component like this :

```
<CustomerSelectorModalComponent @ref=DOMCustomerSelector OnSelectedCustomer=OnCustSelected />
```

and this method :

```
void OnCustSelected(DIMCustomer customer)
        {
            if (CustomerModalMode == customerMode.Owner)
            {

                dIMCheque.OwnerCustomer = customer;
                dIMCheque.ShOwner = customer.ID;
            }
            else if (CustomerModalMode == customerMode.Benefit)
            {
                dIMCheque.BeneficiaryCustomer = customer;
                dIMCheque.ShBeneficiary = customer.ID;
            }
        }
```

but this method dont fire anymore !???

this image show that method handler added for fire but why don't fire ???
[image]

**the component "CustomerSelectorModalComponent" Work Great in another component but don't work in this Parent...
why ????**

I Found The Problem But cant fix them

i want my Component and event handler be Like picture below

[image]

but Blazor event handler is like below

[image]

how can i fix that ...
two component Customer stick to one event handler in Deposit Component

this is my razor in Deposit Component

```
<CustomerComponent @ref=DOMCustomerComponent OnSelectedCustomer=OnCustomerSelected></CustomerComponent>
```

this is my razor in Modal Component

```
<DepositComponent @ref=DOMDeposit OnDepositSelected=OnSelectDeposit />
<CustomerComponent @ref=DOMCustomer OnSelectedCustomer=OnCustSelected />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is Element ID ...
component html element have ID and some work with JavaScript via ID element ...
i have two same component that cause duplicate Id element and break working ...
i generate dynamic ID with GUID and problem solved ...